# Network reply after program ends

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, slot

I wrote program which gets source code of web page from url but i have problem, because this code is prints on screen when program is ending and I can't use data which i downloaded. I think that the problem is because program waits for SIGNAL(finished()). Is any way to process downloaded data in my program before ending?

```
void Get::getCode()
{
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    link = "http://example.com/";
    networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(link)));
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &process, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    //QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(link));
}
```

...

```
    void Process::replyFinished(QNetworkReply* pReply)
{
    QString source(pReply->readAll());
    printf("%s\n", source.toStdString().c_str());
}
```

...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Get get; get.getCode();
    MainWindow window;

    printf("test point\n");

    return a.exec();
    //return 0;}
```

"test point" is first on screen and later html code.

Comment: You could write it to a file?

Comment: I would like to use this code in the same program and write to file isn't necessary, enough that I have write data in QString source, but I can't use this variable in program because it gets data on end of program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network manager runs asynchronous, which means that your main thread continues immediately after calling the get() method.

You can solve this by setting up an event loop which waits until the download is completed:

```
  QEventLoop loop;
  connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
  loop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
```

That should give you the expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code solved half of problem, but I have some questions to about your code. Why you using SLOT(quit())? What mean exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents)? Also I have strange situation, on screen always when i use function contain "loop" is prints this: "QObject::connect: No such signal QNetworkAccessManager::finished() in..." but after that program works normally. The worst is it that still i haven't access to downloaded data from another function.

Comment: The quit() slot is used to stop the event loop once the network manager has finished the download. Otherwise your program would hang forever in the loop.exec() call. The exec() call starts the local event loop. The QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents parameter tells your local event loop to not process any user input, such as mouse/keyboard input. These inputs will be delivered to the main event loop once your local one is finished, which is what you want for such a network processing event loop.